# Continually Stirred Tank-Reactor integration

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Attempting to follow an analysis of the continually stirred tank reactor problem in Logan's Applied Mathematics, but there is one step that I don't follow:

integrating $\frac{d}{dt}(\theta +bc) = 1 + b - (\theta + bc)$ where $\theta$, $c$ are functions of $t$. Logan claims this gives $\theta + bc = 1 + b + De^{-t}$, but why does the integration not give $\theta + bc = t + bt - \int \theta dt - b \int cdt + D$ (with $D$ being the integration constant in each case)?

Comment: You need to use separation of variables. How would you integrate $dy/dt = y+2$ to solve for $y$ as a function of $t$?

Comment: Ahh of course! So we do $\int \frac{1}{g-1-b} dg = \int -1 dt and it all works. Thanks @TedShifrin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g = \theta +bc$, so the equation is now $\dot{g} = 1 + b - g$ which we solve by seperation of variables:

$ \int \frac{1}{g-1-b} dg = \int -1 dt $

$\text{log} (g-1-b) = -t + C $

$g - 1 - b = Ae^{-t}$

so $g = 1 + b + Ae^{-t}$ as claimed.